# WSO2 API manager clustering active-active nodes

Tags: api, wso2, cluster-computing, wso2-api-manager

Wanted to check if we can achieve clustering (active-active) for WSO2 APIM deployed on 2 nodes (all profiles on both nodes)?

Answer (score 2):

You can.

You have to [share databases and mount registry](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0#ClusteringAPIManager2.0.0-InstallingandconfiguringAPIManager) between 2 servers. 
Also you need to [enable clustering](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0#ClusteringAPIManager2.0.0-ConfiguringtheAPIPublisherandAPIStoretobeonthesameclusterdomain) between them.

To share synapse configuration files (of APIs), you needs [enable deployment synchronizing](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer) between 2 servers too. When you configure publishers, it should be configured so that both publishers publish to a single gateway (i.e. one specific node). And dep sync (or something like rSync) should do the synapse file syncing between 2 servers.

Comment: Do I need to configure anything at the profile level (i.e gateway, key manager, traffic manager, etc..) , i mean can i leave the configuration as-is? ex: Gateway on node 1 talks to Key manager on node 1 by default , do i need to load-balance the key managers on both nodes and make the key manager on both the nodes to point to the LB endpoint ?

Comment: Except for publishing to gateway (as I mentioned above) everything else can be used as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You will need to front the two nodes with a load balancer, enable registry mounting, share the databases etc. You can refer the below document for more details on how to cluster the APIM nodes.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0